# operator overloading for structs in D language

Tags: templates, struct, operator-overloading, d

I'm trying to implement aritmetic operations like `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` between 3D vectors in D language (just to get idea if it is worth to migrate from C++ to D, I usually do 3D graphics and numerical math). But I'm perhabs missing something, following code does not work (I tried to do it according to included references).

```
#!/usr/bin/env rdmd
import std.stdio;

// https://dlang.org/spec/operatoroverloading.html
// https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/D-templates-tutorial/blob/master/D-templates-tutorial.md#u-op-v--------opbinarystring-s-vv-v-if-s--opv-op-u--------opbinaryrightstring-s-vv-v-if-s--op

struct vec3f{ float x,y,z; }
vec3f opBinary(string op)(vec3f a, vec3f b){
         static if (op == "+"){ return vec3f(a.x+b.x,a.y+b.y,a.z+b.z); }
    else static if (op == "*"){ return vec3f(a.x*b.x,a.y*b.y,a.z*b.z); }
    else{ static assert(0, "Operator "~op~" not implemented"); }
}

struct vec3(T){ T x,y,z; }
auto opBinary(T,string op)(vec3!T a, vec3!T b){
         static if (op == "+"){ return vec3!T(a.x+b.x,a.y+b.y,a.z+b.z); }
    else static if (op == "*"){ return vec3!T(a.x*b.x,a.y*b.y,a.z*b.z); }
    else{ static assert(0, "Operator "~op~" not implemented"); }
}

void main(){
    //auto a = vec3!float(1.1,2.2,3.2);
    //auto b = vec3!float(3.1,2.2,1.2);
    auto a = vec3f(1.1,2.2,3.2);
    auto b = vec3f(3.1,2.2,1.2);
    writeln(a); writeln(b);
    writeln( a+b );
}
```

The `opBinary` implementation seems to compile fine, but I always get error when I try to use it:

```
./operator_overload.d(27): Error: incompatible types for ((a) + (b)): 'vec3f' and 'vec3f'
Failed: ["dmd", "-v", "-o-", "./operator_overload.d", "-I."]
```

**EDIT** : I also tried `mixin` acoording to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826891/elegant-operator-overloading-in-d). With the same error.

```
struct vec3f{ float x,y,z; }
vec3f opBinary(string op)(vec3f a,vec3f b)if(op=="+"||op=="-"||op=="*"||op=="/"){
     mixin("return vec3f(a.x"~op~"b.x,a.y"~op~"b.y,a.z"~op~"b.z);");
}
```

**EDIT 2** : Yes it have to be part of struct body (I don't know if there is any way how to make it free-standing function ). This works perfect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rdmd
import std.stdio;

struct vec3(T){ 
    float x,y,z; 
    vec3!T opBinary(string op)(vec3!T b) if(op=="+"||op=="-"||op=="*"||op=="/"){ 
        mixin("return vec3!T(x"~op~"b.x,y"~op~"b.y,z"~op~"b.z);"); 
    }
}

void main(){
    auto a = vec3!float(1.1,2.2,3.2);
    auto b = vec3!float(3.1,2.2,1.2);
    writeln(a); writeln(b);
    writeln( a+b );
    writeln( a*b );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't overloaded operator need to be a member of the corresponding struct? Try moving it into the struct (with relevant edits, ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main differences between C++ and D is that user-specified operators in D are always a member of one of the operands. For binary operators, if the struct is the left-hand side the operator is called `opBinary` and for the right-hand side, it's called `opBinaryRight`. It is no other way for good reasons: It makes implementing operator overloading very complicated. You may know that C++ ignores namespaces when searching for an operator overload, e.g. `<<` between `ostream&` and `int` is in the namespace `std`. You don't need to write

```cpp
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World."), std::endl);
```

for

```cpp
std::cout << "Hello World." << std::endl;
```

because of that. D has a module system. Say you have module `a` which gives you type `A` and module `b` which gives you type `B`, both not directly correlated to each other. Then there is this module `c` with type `C` and an operator `*` that takes types `A` and `B` and returns a `C` because `C` relates `A` and `B`. Now I import `a` and `b` and use `*` on two objects. How should the compiler know about `c`?

Comment: A minor correction: C++ does not ignore namespaces while looking up functions. It uses argument dependent lookup which tries to resolve the function in the namespaces of its arguments.

Comment: It does not require to annotate the namespace to operators while it does so for functions. But yes, argument dependent lookup is not a thing in D. It is also very unlikely to be a future feature.